# Plotting 1D Time Series from 2D Hourly DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to plot a year's worth of utility data downloaded from my utility provider. The data is provided in a matrix where each row is a different day (most recent at the top), and each column is an hour of the day (11:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 1:00 PM, etc). I'd like to transform this 2D DataFrame into a 1D Timeseries, then plot the series.

Using .stack() gets me close, but I can't seem to create a datetime from the date and time column after they are stacked. Also, when plotted it plots the hours correctly from left to right, but the dates descend from left to right. For example it plots the 25th (1am, 2am 3am, etc), 24th (1am, 2am, 3am, etc), 23rd (1am, 2am, 3am, etc). I'm sure this will fix itself after a true datetime is created.

The code below generates a small sample df, but in the real data set all 24 hours are columns and all dates of the year are rows.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['06/25/17','06/24/17','06/23/17'], '12:00 AM':
[1,2,3],'1:00 AM':[4,5,6],'2:00 AM':[7,8,9],})
df.set_index(['Date'], inplace = True)
df
```

The goal would be to have a series where the index is the time series and the utility usage is the data.

Thank you!

Comment: The correct final format for this will be in chronological order, not ordered by data values:

06/23/17 12:00  3
06/23/17   1:00  6
06/23/17   2:00  9
06/24/17 12:00  2
06/24/17   1:00  5
06/24/17   2:00  8

etc

Comment: see my revised post.  Initially, I forgot to convert the index to a timestamp.  Once the data type is correct you can plot in chronological order regardless of the order in the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) your data frame, concatenate the columns `Date` and `level_0` to make a time stamp. Then set the index to the timestamp and drop the extra columns.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['06/25/17','06/24/17','06/23/17'], '12:00 AM':
[1,2,3],'1:00 AM':[4,5,6],'2:00 AM':[7,8,9],})
df.set_index(['Date'], inplace = True)

#Unstack and reset index
df = df.unstack().reset_index()

#concatenate timestamp and convert to datetime
df['Timestamp'] = df['Date'] + ' '+ df['level_0']
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],format="%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p")
df =df.sort_values(by='Timestamp')
df = df.set_index('Timestamp')

#drop extra columns
df = df.drop(['Date','level_0'],axis=1)
```

returns `df` looking like:

```
                     0
Timestamp             
2017-06-23 00:00:00  3
2017-06-23 01:00:00  6
2017-06-23 02:00:00  9
2017-06-24 00:00:00  2
2017-06-24 01:00:00  5
2017-06-24 02:00:00  8
2017-06-25 00:00:00  1
2017-06-25 01:00:00  4
2017-06-25 02:00:00  7
```

You could then plot your time series with

```
df.plot()
```

Yielding:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @TheGadgeteer Great! Please consider accepting the answer

Comment: @thegadgeteer See my revised solution.  Once I noticed your timestamp included an AM or PM, I added the correct format for the date.

Comment: Do you know how to get rid of the date and just plot the hours (and minutes)?